# undefined method for nil:NilClass in my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting a:

```
undefined method `lat' for nil:NilClass
```

error and I want to solve it. To be exact the message is:

```
NoMethodError in Static_pages#faq

Showing /home/christophecompaq/Pop/app/views/layouts/_signed_in_header.html.erb where line #101 raised:

undefined method `lat' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #101):

98: <div id="javascript_tags with lat and lang">
99:   <%= javascript_tag do %>
100: user_latitude = "<%=raw @user.lat %>";
101: user_longitude = "<%=raw @user.lng %>";
102: 
103:    <% end %>
104:  </div>
```

I have 2 other pages in the Static Pages folder where I also get this error - 'Contact Us' and 'About Us'.

But when I take the code below out of my _signed_in_header.html.erb and paste it in my file called show.html.erb, the errors stop.

```
 <div id="javascript_tags with lat and lang">
  <%= javascript_tag do %>
 user_latitude = "<%=raw @user.lat %>";
 user_longitude = "<%=raw @user.lng %>";

    <% end %>
  </div>
```

But the thing is, I need to have that code in the _signed_in_header.html.erb.

So I suppose my question is, 'where can I define user_latitude = "<%=raw @user.lat %>" and user_longitude = "<%=raw @user.lng %>" so my pages will recognise them without giving me errors?' I've tried the application controller, the static pages controller, but I'm still getting problems. Maybe I have to put something in the routes file, I'm not sure? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you include the code for the `faq` method in `StaticPagesController`?

Comment: sorry, had to go out.I have nothing in my faq method, simply 'def faq
  end'. Yet I don't have any problems with nothing in the faq method and with the javascript_tag code in my question in the show.html.erb file.

Comment: What about the `ApplicationController`? You have to find where `@user` is being defined.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look into the controller method where you defined the `@user` instance variable -- probably `Static_pages#faq`.

What's happening is that `@user` is equal to `nil` when you passed it to the view. So when you try to send it the `lat` method, that generates the `undefined method`lat' for nil:NilClass` error.